# How to only stub on a certain call with sinon.stub()

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I want to stub `doSomething` to callback with an error. However, I only want it to callback with an error on the first response. I would like to restore the stub after the first call

In order to stub the first call, I can do this:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(someOjbect, "doSomething");
stub.onCall(0).callsArgWith(5, mockError);
```

How do I restore the stub after the first call? e.g.

```
stub.onCall(1).restore();
```

The above obviously doesn't work, just wanted to give an example of what I want to achieve

Comment: Why do you want to restore it after the first call? If you are writing a test then you'd want to mock both first and second calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will stub only the first call, but I'm not sure if it'll work for your use case:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(someObject, 'doSomething', function(args) {

  someObject.doSomething.restore();
  return mockData;
});
```